# Using docusign to sign a batch of PDFs

Tags: pdf, docusignapi

We want to do the following:

```
 1) upload 2 to 100 or so PDFs per day
 2) have two people digitally sign each individual PDF
 2a) The first signature needs to be a "certifying signature" - with certifying rights allowing one additional signature in the pdf
```

From a simple test of the system, it appears the process is - via the UI:

```
 1) Upload the pdfs via the browser
 1a) with the browser UI "place" signatures (Position etc.) in the PDFs (can be 100)
 2a) First Person Signs the Batch of PDFs and sends the Batch to a recipient.
 2b) The recipient signs and "sends them back"
```

Manually putting in signature fields in 100 PDF documents per day is quite a Task. Out PDFs can be generated with Signature form fields.

Can the Docusign System find specific form fields and use those for specific users - to fill in a digital signature?
Is this possible/and better done with the API? Is there a example or document that describes this somewhere?

I'm new to this System, so this/these question(s) might be completely naive.

Answer (score 0):

**Same underlying document is being sent (eg an order form)**
If the pdfs are different versions of the same form or document then you use a [template](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-create-templates). Eg, if the documents are contracts being sent for approval to different people, then they are all the same underlying "contract document," but with different values for customer, dates, etc.

Easiest is to first "tag" the document using a template via the web interface, then use the same template for the subsequent documents. When you upload a new document, DocuSign will also automatically suggest which of your template matches the new document, saving additional steps.

If you have just a couple of different underlying documents then you'd create a matching set of templates. Since a matching template is suggested when the user uploads a doc, it means that the end users only have to tag ad hoc documents that they are sending or when a document format changes.

**Documents that vary**
For these cases, using a template with [Anchor Text Tabs](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/cdse-user-guide-docusign-tags-using-anchor-text) works well. An Anchor Text Tab tells the tab (eg a "Signature" tab) that, rather than being placed at a specific page and x/y co-ordinates, the tab should instead look for specific text in the document. So you create a template with an Anchor Text Tab that will look for the string "Sign here:" the tab will then place itself nearby (you can give the x and y offsets from the text.)

Anchor Text Tabs can also look for text that is "invisible" on the page (same color as the background). So you can change your docs to include invisible strings which will enable the Anchor Text Tabs to find their correct locations on the pages.

**API** All of the above can be done via the API. Since templates are often just created when a new document is set up, you may want to create the template using the web UI. Then, using the API, select which specific template should be applied to the doc that you've uploaded with the API.